# How to know which Support Library version my Android app is using?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

In my `gradle.properties` I have this:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

When I `Make Project`, I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. From Android Studio, I go to `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...` I am getting 15 references in 9 files to be changed:

[image]

Reading https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-androidx-tip-tricks-and-guidance-88d5de238876, I see that the step 1 of the recommended approach to migrate is to Update to Support Library version 28. In order to do that, I want to know what Support Library version the code of my app is at. Where can I see that? In some of my `.java` files I have found the following:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
```

In my `app\build.gradle` I have this: `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`.

Do any of the lines above reveals or helps to reveal the Support Library version that the code of my app is at? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is that they suggest upgrading all of the possible support libraries to `28.0`.

Those are basically anything that starts with `com.android.support:`

e.g.:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

The recommendation there is so the migration in the AS will have to do minimal guessing on how to migrate it.

So to stricly answer your question, the version you use is the version you have in `gradle.files`.

Comment: The only reference to Support Library that I have in my Gradle files is `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`. All other references, as I mentioned in my question, are in my `.java` files.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya Multidex is probably exception to that "rule". I think you can skip that step and continue with the guide how to migrate. Or I am not sure what is not working?

Comment: From what I understand, my next step should now be to change the 15 references in 9 files that I show in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sXkj.png. I obtained those references by using `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...` from Android Studio.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya isn't there a button at the bottom of that window that says "Migrate" or something like that? You should be just able to click "Ok, I find your results sufficient"

Comment: You are right! There is a button that says "Do Refactor". I hadn't seen it. I thought all the help from Android Studio was to identify the code that needed to be changed and it was the work of the programmer to perform those changes manually by himself/herself. I'll try that button. Thank you!